# Using Frame.Navigate with typeof(UserControl)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

It is possible to do so? Do I need to use only `Page` objects instead?
I've tried to `Navigate` to a `UserControl` and I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Project.exe
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType)

However, if I use a `Page`, it works perfectly.

I posed an entire project using UserControls and I'm afraid I will have to outline it back :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Frame.Navigate()` methods description it says for it's first parameter

> The **page** to navigate to, specified as a type reference to its partial
>   class type. (A type reference is given as System.Type for .NET, or a
>   TypeName helper struct for C++/CX)

So I'm sorry, but you need a `Page` or a class derived from the `Page` for navigation